# How to set today date and time as default in angular-moment-picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-moment

I am using angular-moment-picker input for datetimepicker, and I want to set today date and current time on the input. Here is my source code. can you please help me.
Thank you

```
 <input class="form-control"
                       format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"
                       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                       moment-picker="startDate"
                       id="startDate"
                       ng-model="startDate">
```

Comment: add script code

Comment: @Mr_Perfect thankyou for answering my issue. this is what I  am looking for.is there any attribute to add to the input an instanciate the date from angularjs controller ?  ng-model="startDate" doesn't work if i am adding startDate=new Date(); at the angularjs controller

Comment: So, what value you want to display in input? I mean full value or only date and time?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect, I want juste to display only date and time as it is inthe format attribute. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set default value `startDate` when controller initialized

```
angular
  .module('Demo', ['moment-picker'])
  .controller('DemoController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

      $scope.startDate = moment();
  }]);
```

Comment: If I am using datepicker in a timeline chart. Can i set initial value as the time clicked on the chart i.e value returned from d3.mouse(this)? Is it necessary to set the variable at the start of the controller itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Use moment() method in script file.

http://embed.plnkr.co/GqJMbeQ5UtSbIutn8elf/

Answer (score 0):

You can set start date by using the start-date attribute in your input control. The value should be an moment object.

```
<input class="form-control"
    format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
    moment-picker="startDate"
    id="startDate"
    ng-model="startDate"
    start-date="startDate">
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3oph64zd/15/). Here I have used moment and angular-moment library and module respectively