# unable to set custom time as initial value in moment-picker

Tags: angularjs, angular-moment-picker

I am trying to set initial value of datepicker to be the time on the chart where the user clicked. The value is being stored in the variable used in ng-model but the it still displays the placeholder instead.

```
<input class="form-control" ng-init="vm.input" ng-model="vm.input" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" placeholder="Click here to select a date"
       moment-picker="vm.input" style="width:25em;height:25px;" format="LL LTS">
```

in controller I am passing the value to be displayed initially:

```
scope.vm.input = moment(xScale.invert(newData[0])).format("ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss z");//Sun Feb 18 2018 05:16:29
```

Am I missing something ? I tried the solution given in this question: [How to set today date and time as default in angular-moment-picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44201003/how-to-set-today-date-and-time-as-default-in-angular-moment-picker?s=12|83.2661) . But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is using `scope` and `vm as this` together in controller, description is:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
    {{vm.input}}
</div>

app.controller("ctrl", function() {
   var vm = this;
   //do not use scope.vm, vm is scope for this controller
   vm.input = "Hello World";
})
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.input = moment().format("ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss z");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">

<input class="form-control" ng-init="vm.input" ng-model="vm.input" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" placeholder="Click here to select a date"
       moment-picker="vm.input" style="width:25em;height:25px;" format="LL LTS">
</div>
```

Comment: I am using scope.vm intentionally as the code is part of the timeline chart that I am drawing using d3.js. So for the variable to accessible, it needs to be written in such manner.--function drawScatterPlot (element, scope, configuration)

Comment: The value selected on datepicker is being passed to controller correctly indicating that issue is not with using scope.vm. Its only setting the initial value that is causing problem.

Comment: The above solution will work only for setting static values right ?

Comment: @user2128, no isn't, i change static value to `moment js` as dynamic date time